# Optimize python for Connected Component Labeling Area of Subsets

Tags: python, cython, numba

I have a  binary map on which I do Connected Component Labeling and get something like this for a 64x64 grid - http://pastebin.com/bauas0NJ

Now I want to group them by label, so that I can find their area and their center of mass. This is what I do:

```
#ccl_np is the computed array from the previous step (see pastebin)
#I discard the label '1' as its the background
unique, count = np.unique(ccl_np, return_counts = True)
xcm_array = []
ycm_array = []

for i in range(1,len(unique)):
    subarray = np.where(ccl_np == unique[i])
    xcm_array.append("{0:.5f}".format((sum(subarray[0]))/(count[i]*1.)))
    ycm_array.append("{0:.5f}".format((sum(subarray[1]))/(count[i]*1.)))

final_array = zip(xcm_array,ycm_array,count[1:])
```

I want a fast code (as I will be doing this for grids of size 4096x4096) and was told to check out numba. Here's my naive attempt :

```
unique, inverse, count = np.unique(ccl_np, return_counts = True, return_inverse = True)
xcm_array = np.zeros(len(count),dtype=np.float32)
ycm_array = np.zeros(len(count),dtype=np.float32)
inverse = inverse.reshape(64,64)

@numba.autojit
def mysolver(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count):
    for i in range(64):
        for j in range(64):
            pos = inverse[i][j]
            local_count = count[pos]
            xcm_array[pos] += i/(local_count*1.)
            ycm_array[pos] += j/(local_count*1.)


mysolver(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count)

final_array = zip(xcm_array,ycm_array,count)
```

To my surprise, using numba was slower or at best equal to the speed of the previous way. What am I doing wrong ?
Also, can this be done in Cython and will that be faster ?

I am using the included packages in the latest Anaconda python 2.7 distribution.

Comment: Try changing `inverse[i][j]` to `inverse[i,j]`. This should be much more efficient for accessing elements of a numpy array when using numba or not.

Comment: @JoshAdel I changed it to `[i,j]` and its about 2 % faster.

Comment: Code seems to be removed from pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue might be that you are timing jit'd code incorrectly. The first time you run the code, your timing includes the time it takes numba to compile the code. This is called warming up the jit. If you call it again, that cost is gone.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

unique, inverse, count = np.unique(ccl_np, return_counts = True, return_inverse = True)
xcm_array = np.zeros(len(count),dtype=np.float32)
ycm_array = np.zeros(len(count),dtype=np.float32)
inverse = inverse.reshape(64,64)

def mysolver(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count):
    for i in range(64):
        for j in range(64):
            pos = inverse[i][j]
            local_count = count[pos]
            xcm_array[pos] += i/(local_count*1.)
            ycm_array[pos] += j/(local_count*1.)

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def mysolver_nb(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count):
    for i in range(64):
        for j in range(64):
            pos = inverse[i,j]
            local_count = count[pos]
            xcm_array[pos] += i/(local_count*1.)
            ycm_array[pos] += j/(local_count*1.)
```

Then the timings with `timeit` which runs the code multiple times. First the plain python version:

```
In [4]:%timeit mysolver(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop
```

and then with numba:

```
In [5]: %timeit mysolver_nb(xcm_array, ycm_array, inverse, count)
The slowest run took 3630.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean         that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.1 µs per loop
```

The numba code is ~1000 times faster.

Comment: Thanks ! For a 256x256 grid I got 390x speed up :) Didn't know about "warming up" the JIT compiler.

Comment: Delving deeper into the docs, I have changed the signature to this : `@jit([(float32[:], float32[:], int64[:,:], int64[:])],nopython=True,cache=True)` and its now 710x faster ! :)  The jit was defaulting to float64 for the arrays earlier